# How to run OpenACC + OpenCV with PGI in Windows?

Tags: opencv, openacc, pgi

I tried to run the code below:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <omp.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::string imgstr = "input.bmp";
    cv::Mat imgmat = cv::imread(imgstr, cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    imgmat.convertTo(imgmat, CV_64FC1, 1.0 / 255.0);

    double st = omp_get_wtime();

    int i, j;
    double res = 0.0;
    #pragma acc parallel loop
    for (i =0; i <= 10; i++) {
        for (j =0; j <=10; j++) {
            res =res+ imgmat.at<double>(i, j);
        }
    }

    double runtime = omp_get_wtime() - st;
    printf("\n total: %f s\n", runtime);
}
```

with `pgcc -fast -ta=nvidia,managed -Minfo=accel -o runEx runEx.c -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core && ./runEx` in PGI, but I get an error saying

```
can't find include file opencv2/opencv.hpp
```

However, the code above compiles and runs successfully in Visual Studio without using OpenACC

can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you need to include the path to header files using the "-I/path/to/openvc/include" flag on the command line.  You'll also want to include the library path (via the "-L/path/to/opencv/lib") so it can find the libraries.

Though given "pgcc" is a C compiler, you'll have additional issues given you're using C++ header files and C++ constructs in your code.  Current PGI releases do not support C++ on Windows.

Comment: how can I compile C++ code with OpenACC then? I have to use an outdated version of PGI or another compiler?

Comment: I also tried `-I/C:/opencv/build/include/opencv2 -I/C:/opencv/build/include -I/C:/opencv/build/include/opencv  -L/C:/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib` and I still get the same `can't find include file opencv2/opencv.hpp` error as before

Comment: You'll need to use Linux for now if you want PGI OpenACC support in C++.  An NVIDIA HPC C++ compiler (the successor to PGI) for Windows is in development but wont be available for some time.

Comment: I prefer to use Windows. Is there another compiler that can work for C++ in Windows besides PGI?

Comment: "/C:/" is an incorrect PATH prefix name.  Try a DOS path "-IC:/", or possibly a cygwin path such as "-I/c/".  Looks like your mixing the two different style paths

Comment: I also tried the `-I` and `-L`, but replaced `C:` with `C`, and now the error is `core.hpp header must be compiled as C++`. If I replaced `pgcc` with `pgCC`, I get the same error. If I try `pgcpp`, it says `command not found`

Comment: Good, glad you we are least able to get the PATHs correct.  Windows is case insensitive so "pgcc" and "pgCC" is the same thing and pgcpp was discontinued many years ago.

Comment: You might consider usin WSL2.  While we don't officially support WSL, I've had a few users successfully install the NVIDIA HPC SDK and run OpenACC based Linux programs.  For example: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/wsl-and-pgi-compiler-works-great/136530/7